# Converting Discord bot commands to Slash commands using app_commands in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a Discord bot written in Python that uses the **app_commands** library for command handling. Currently, I have a command called "play" that allows users to play a song from YouTube. However, I want to migrate this command to a slash command.

Working command without Slash:

```
@commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
        elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, "channel", None):
            return await ctx.send("first join vc smh")
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
        if vc.is_playing() or not vc.queue.is_empty:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
            await ctx.send(f"Added `{search.title}` to the queue")
        else:
            await vc.play(search)
            await ctx.send(f"Now playing `{search.title}`")

        vc.ctx = ctx
```

My try with slash:
(Bot joins the voice channel, but does not play anything)

```
@app_commands.command(name="play", description="Play a song from YouTube.")
    async def play(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, search: str):
        if not interaction.guild.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await interaction.user.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
        elif not getattr(interaction.user.voice.channel, "channel", None):
            return await interaction.response.send_message("You need to join a voice vhannel first.")
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.voice_client

        if vc.is_playing() or not vc.queue.is_empty:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="In queue:", description=f"`{search.title}`", color=discord.Color.purple())
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        else:
            await vc.play(search)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Now playing:", description=f"`{search.title}`", color=discord.Color.blue())
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

When using the command I get this error:
`discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'play' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`

I think the problem is that "search: wavelink. YouTubeTrack" is not used in the command line, as in the code without slash.

My discord.py version is: **2.2.3**
Im using the code inside a **Cog**

I don't know how solve this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the part that you're calling the "command line" is actually called the function arguments, sometimes called parameters. The bit with the colon is called a 
 type hint, which indicates what type of parameter the function expects. https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_arguments.asp https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you're passing [play](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wavelink.html#wavelink.Player.play) a `str` and not a [YouTubeTrack](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wavelink.html#youtubetrack). It appears that you're making use of the [WaveLink](https://github.com/PythonistaGuild/Wavelink) library. You can convert your `search` into a `YouTubeTrack` like this:

```py
search = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(search, return_first=True)
```

Note that it is possible for `wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search` to return `None` (i.e.: no results, or maybe your internet goes out), you should make sure to handle this edge case.

<sub>This code is untested, please lmk if it doesn't work and I'll give it another go.</sub>